# QtQuick and KDE theming issues

Tags: qml, kde-plasma

I've made some QtQuick programs, and I thought it was all working fine, till I tried them out on my laptop, which is running KDE, with the Breeze Dark theme.

A simple program with a label is barely readable:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window
{
    visible: true

    Label
    {
        font.pointSize: 20
        text: "Hello world!"
    }
}
```

With KDE Breeze Dark:

[image]

With XFCE:

[image]

I have a customised combobox too, and it looks terrible under KDE. It has the same issue on the default KDE theme, just with the colours inverted:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick 2.7

Window
{
    visible: true

    minimumWidth: 200
    minimumHeight: 200

    ComboBox
    {
        id: combo

        model: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]

        width: 150
        height: 50

        delegate: ItemDelegate
        {
            id: item

            width: parent.width

            contentItem: Text
            {
                text: modelData
                font.pointSize: 15
            }

            MouseArea
            {
                anchors.fill: parent

                hoverEnabled: true
                propagateComposedEvents: true

                onClicked: mouse.accepted = false
                onPressed: mouse.accepted = false
                onReleased: mouse.accepted = false
                onDoubleClicked: mouse.accepted = false
                onPositionChanged: mouse.accepted = false
                onPressAndHold: mouse.accepted = false

                onEntered:
                {
                    item.highlighted = true
                }

                onExited:
                {
                    item.highlighted = false
                }
            }
        }

        contentItem: Text
        {
            id: dropDown

            anchors.fill: parent

            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter

            font.pointSize: 15

            text: combo.displayText
        }
    }
}
```

With KDE Breeze Dark:

[image]

With XFCE:

[image]

So, I'm not sure if this is a KDE issue, or a QtQuick issue. 
I guess I want to know how I can either disable KDE theming of certain programs, or modify my Qml to display my programs nicely when themed. 
I couldn't find barely any literature on QtQuick theming, aside from some proposals or ways to manually implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SystemPalette](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-systempalette.html). For example:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    color: palette.window

    Label {
        font.pointSize: 20
        text: "Hello world!"
    }
    SystemPalette {
        id: palette
        colorGroup: SystemPalette.Active
    }
}
```